# React Native Building failed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project built with Expo. I am using Firebase for google authentication and Firestore to save the data. When I am running the app using `expo start` after I run the app on my emulator I am getting the following error:

[image]

I tried running `yarn install` and try running the expo server again but the same result. Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: What is your Firebase SDK version? I saw someone fixed it by reinstalling Firebase at Discord.

Comment: My firebase SDK version is 9.6.10.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to latest version that is 9.8.3 right now?

Comment: I updated the firebase version to the latest 9.8.3 and then tried running the app again but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, I found this [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/) that will help you with your `React Native` project with `Firebase`.

You should create a [metro.config.js](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#adding-more-file-extensions-to--assetexts) file in the project root if you're using expo to address this problem. Add the cjs file extension to the file.

More file extensions that are considered an asset are being added to metro.config.js. By default, many image, video, audio, and font formats (such as jpg, png, mp4, mp3, and ttf) are included. Create a metro.config.js file in the project root to add new asset file extensions.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config'); const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname); defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('db'); module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

Code Example:

```
module.exports = { 
  transformer: { 
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({ 
      transform: { 
        experimentalImportSupport: false, 
        inlineRequires: true, 
      }, 
    }), 
   }, 
//added this 

 resolver: { 
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'], 
  }, 
};
```

As an alternative solution, it appears that the most recent version has various flaws. All you have to do now is downgrade to `firebase@9.6.11`. Primarily, use this command to uninstall the Firebase package.

`npm uninstall firebase`

Now, execute this command to install Firebase 9.6.11.

`npm install firebase@9.6.11`

Comment: Thank You So much for your answer. I have been stuck on this error for a very long time now.